# How does the program decides which method to run because the object is of child class

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding, constructor-overloading

So I have the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Shape{
   double length, breadth;

   Shape(double l, double b) { //Constructor to initialize a Shape object  
      length = l;
      breadth = b;
   }

   Shape(double len) { //Constructor to initialize another Shape object  
      length = breadth = len;
   }

   double calculate(){ // To calculate the area of a shape object
      return length * breadth ;
   }
}

public class Test1 extends Shape {
   double height;

   Test1(double l, double h) {
      super(l);
      height = h;
   }

   Test1(double l, double b, double h) {
      super(l, b);
      height = h;
   }
   @Override
   double calculate(){
      return length*breadth*height;
   }   

   public static void main(String args[]) {
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       double l=sc.nextDouble();
       double b=sc.nextDouble();   
       double h=sc.nextDouble(); 
    
       Test1 myshape1 = new Test1(l,h);
       Test1 myshape2 = new Test1(l,b,h);
    
       double volume1;
       double volume2;
    
       volume1 = myshape1.calculate();
       volume2 = myshape2.calculate();
    
       System.out.println(volume1);
       System.out.println(volume2);
   }
}
```

and I don't understand how does it decides which of the `calculate()` method to run because both of them are called from child class object yet one of them decides to run parent class method.

Is it related to constructor overloading? If yes how?

Comment: They both run the calculate method in `Test1`. What makes you think `calculate` in `Shape` is being called?

Comment: It doesn't run the method from the parent class. It runs the calculate method from the child class. You just ignore 1 of your inputs when creating one of your objects. So if you enter 1, 2 and 3 you create 1 Object with length 1, breadth 2 and height 3 and another object with length and breadth 1 and height 3.

Comment: Can you explain the input and outputs:

the output is:

`16.0\n`
`24.0\n`

for input:

`2.0 3.0 4.0`

Comment: Easy: 2*3*4=24, 2*2*4=16 - As i said you ignore one of the inputs for one of your objects and give it the first input for both length and breadth.

Comment: Step through your code with a debugger and you'll understand the output.

Comment: @ArinPaliwal Look at this in your code when you create one of your Shapes: new `Test1(l,h)` <- You only pass the `l` and `h` to it, so you really shouldn't be surprised that this object doesn't know or care about what you input for `b` is

Comment: I got it thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructor overloading has nothing to do with "*which method runs*". Constructors are only used to initialize the instance, and "which method runs" may be a question related to *method overloading*, which is not the case in your question.

In both of cases:

```java
volume1 = myshape1.calculate();
volume2 = myshape2.calculate();
```

the lowest available implementation of `calculate()` in the `Test1` ... -> `java.lang.Object` class hierarchy, is invoked - that is `Test1::calculate`, in your case.

You do *not* invoke the superclass's `calculate()`, but rather, your class's `calculate()` uses fields inherited from the superclass `Shape`, as:

```java
double calculate(){
      return length*breadth*height;
}
```

When you instantiate class, it's created with all the members (even private) of its superclasses, and that's why you use the fields of superclasses, as if they were defined in the class in question.

Side-note: `private` members of the superclass, are not directly accessible, in the subclass. You need appropriate accessors/getters for accessing them.

Answer (score 0):

If the method is not `private`, `static` or `final`, then the method is virtual by default.

That is, the method of the lowest class will be used.
You have overridden the method in `Test1`, so it will be called. I advise you to write `@Override` over a method to show yourself and others that this method is inherited.